# How do I refer to a class template, as a template, from within its own class definition?

Tags: c++, templates

Here's the scenario:

```
template <template <typename> class T, typename V>
struct parent {
    void do_something();
};

template <typename V>
struct child : public parent<child, V> {
    void do_something(V argument);
    using parent<child, V>::do_something; // C3200: invalid template argument for template parameter 'IMPL', expected a class template
};
```

The above code fails to compile on the given line with the given error (MSVC 9.0).  However if I write this instead, outside of the class definition for `child`:

```
template <typename V>
struct parent_identity_meta {
    typedef typename parent<child, V> type; // no error!
};
```

I can now successfully do the following, within `child`:

```
using parent_identity_meta<V>::type::do_something;
```

I know there's a limitation (alleviated in C++11) that you can't typedef against a template, but I don't think that's what I'm running into here, otherwise the typedef in `parent_identity_meta` would fail.  It seems like `child` refers to the *template* when not inside of its own class definition, and to the *class being generated* from within itself.

This is pretty understandable (having to write `child<V>` every single time would be painful); but is there any way to override this behaviour?

Comment: I can't explain the error message, but I noticed that `do_something` is private. I think that's a problem, too.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: That fixes it for me. I'm not sure why though. Ooh, actually I think I get it (:

Comment: Wow you guys are fast.  I have both variants of the code in place in parallel right now, and believe it or not, if I change one of them to ::child and leave the other as-is, the compiler crashes.  But that's a side issue... I'll let you know if I can get the ::variant to work.

Comment: @jogojapan in my real life code I'm using struct, not class.  Sorry, this is a sanitized example I typed straight into the question box.

Comment: The reason is called "injected class name". Inside of `child`, the identifier `child` is an injected class name that refers to the complete type. This makes writing functions easier that use the complete type, like assignment operators, in heavily templated classes. `child operator=(child const&);` instead of `child<V> operator=(child<V> const&);`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie That did it in the end (my real code is namespaced, took a minute for me to think to fully qualify it)!  Thanks very much.  Wanna post a full answer that I can upvote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a place where C++03 and C++11 are different from each other. The relevant part of the standard is `[temp.local]/1`. In C++03, this states:

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an injected-class-name (clause 9). The injected-class-name can be used with or without a template-argument-list. When it is used without a template- argument-list, it is equivalent to the injected-class-name followed by the template-parameters of the class template enclosed in <>. When it is used with a template-argument-list, it refers to the specified class template specialization, which could be the current specialization or another specialization.

This means that `child` (without any template arguments) refers to the specialization `child<V>`. In C++11, it was changed to:

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an injected-class-name (Clause 9). The injected- class-name can be used as a template-name or a type-name. When it is used with a template-argument-list, as a template-argument for a template template-parameter, or as the final identifier in the elaborated-type-specifier of a friend class template declaration, it refers to the class template itself. Otherwise, it is equivalent to the template-name followed by the template-parameters of the class template enclosed in <>.

Note in particular `When it is used ... as a template-argument for a template template-parameter ... it refers to the class template itself.`. This means that in C++11, your code would be correct.

Comment: Ah, beat me by a few seconds :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference and the C++11 info.  MSVC9 doesn't do C++11, MSVC10 does some of it.  I switch back and forth--I've probably done this in MSVC10 and not noticed that it didn't not work.

Comment: Haha, thanks @SethCarnegie... I was going to upvote yours since, really, you got to the answer first :)  Thanks both of you.

Comment: @MarkMcKenna no necessario, this answer is better than the one I would have given anyway.